# What is an "aha"moment?

Tags: meaning

M-W dict listed it as :  a moment of sudden realization, inspiration, insight, recognition, or comprehension. Could you please better describe aha moment with examples?
Thanks,

Comment: ***Aha:***  The definition of aha is something said to express surprise, understanding, or a discovery.
*An example of aha is what you say when you find a restaurant for which you’ve been looking.*
*An example of aha is what you say when you figure out the answer to a mystery.* http://www.yourdictionary.com/aha

Comment: We don't do straight definitions of well-established words here. That's what dictionaries are for. If you can describe what doubts and uncertainties still remain after reading that M-W definition, and of course the definitions of any unfamiliar words *it* uses, edit your post, and we will be more than happy to discuss those specific concerns. Alternatively, if you found that one definition unsatisfactory or insufficent, you can look up how many several dictionaries define the term, simultaneously, using the convenient online tool [OneLook.com](http://onelook.com).

Comment: Perhaps one way to define the term is with it's antonym -- an "aw shit moment".  That's when you realize that you really screwed up royally.

Comment: I would say epiphany

Comment: @HotLicks Synonym: *holy shit!*

Comment: It's the instant when you realize that "[Take on Me](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZKspel3BEog)" and the parody version of "[Take on Me](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8HE9OQ4FnkQ)" are going to stay in your head until your dying day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most well-known *aha* moment of all time:

> "**Eureka**" (/jʊərˈriːkə/) is an interjection used to celebrate a discovery or invention.
>
> The exclamation 'Eureka!' is famously attributed to the ancient Greek scholar Archimedes. He reportedly proclaimed "Eureka!" when he stepped into a bath and noticed that the water level rose—he **suddenly understood** that the volume of water displaced must be equal to the volume of the part of his body he had submerged. -[Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eureka_%28word%29)

Answer (score 0):

> light-bulb moment

As often seen in comics with a picture of a light-bulb above someone's head. Usually implies that someone has just had a bright idea, solved a puzzle, etc.

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/light-bulb-moment